# Displaying a parent key if a value in subarray exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a script with two variables $state and $sectors.  I want to display the sector if the state is in that sector.  The example below uses 'Arizona' as the state and it should output the sector as 'southwest' but I do not think I am working with the array properly:

```
    <?php

    $state = 'Arizona';

    $sectors = array(
                "Southeast" => array(
                        'name' => 'Southeast',
                        'states'    => array('Alabama', 'Georgia', 'Florida', 'South Carolina', 'North Carolina', 'Louisiana', 'Tennessee', 'Kentucky', 'West Virginia', 'Mississippi')
                ),
                    "Southwest" => array(
                            'name' => 'Southwest',
                            'states'    => array('California', 'Arizona', 'New Mexico', 'Utah')
                    )
    );

        function has_recursive($sectors, $state)
        {
            foreach ($state as $key => $value) {
                if (!isset($sectors[$key])) {
                    return false;
            }
            if (is_array($sectors[$key]) && false === has_recursive($sectors[$key], $value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (has_recursive($sectors, $state) == true){
     // false or true
        echo $sector['name'];  // Displays Southwest
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: You surely mean `'states' => array('California', 'Arizona', 'New Mexico', 'Utah')`? (note the `array(...)`)

Comment: is it better to do `"Southeast" => array('Alabama', 'Georgia', 'Florida', 'South Carolina', 'North Carolina', 'Louisiana', 'Tennessee', 'Kentucky', 'West Virginia', 'Mississippi')` how do I retrieve the $sector

Comment: @bwoebi Is that right if I use Marks recommendation below.. I need the $sec[name]?

Comment: you also just could fetch the $key too in the foreach statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_sector($sector_array, $state_name) {

    foreach ($sector_array as $sec) 
        if (in_array($state_name, $sec))
            return $sec['name'];

    return false;
}
```

Given `$state` and `$sectors` as defined in your question...

```
echo get_sector($sectors, $state); // prints "Southwest"
```

**UPDATE regarding comment:**

There are several different approaches to the "not found" return value. What works best for your application is up to you, but here are a few examples:

```
return false;

//This would be used like this:
if (!$sect = get_sector($sectors, $state))
    echo "A custom error message"
else
    echo "Sector = " . $sect;
```

OR you could return a specific string:

```
return "Sector not found."; 
// Return a standard error message
```

OR a customized string:

```
return "No sector match for the state of " . $state_name; 
// Return a specific error message
```

Comment: @Rizzo False if not found was my original thought. I have updated the function to instead return "Sector not found" if there is not match.

Comment: @Rizzo I updated again with more information about the return value :)

Answer (score 0):

This function should work.

```
function getSector($stateName, $sectorList) {
   foreach($sectorList as $sector) {
      if( in_array($stateName, $sector['states'] ) {
         return $sector['name'];   
      }
   }
 // If state is not found
 return 'NOT FOUND';
}
```

Example of use in your code is:

```
echo getSector($state, $sectors);
```

Comment: There's hardly any difference with this or [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23639882/) given before you. The functionality is 100% the same, when the return is slightlyyyyyy different.